# Can a 1.8" HDD from an iPod be used in a laptop that takes 1.8" drives?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

Or would I need to make some modifications to the HDD to get it to fit or work with the laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really depends on the type of connecter your laptop is using. Typically newer Laptops use SATA or m-sata connector so the hard-drives in the i-pod classic cannot directly be used in a laptop as the hard-drive in the ipod classic use a zif-connector (flat ribbon cable type).

Sata (2.5") and M-sata (typical for newer 1.8"):

[image: SATA and M-SATA Connector]

Older 1.8" Laptops might use micro-sata or even Zif-connector. With the exception of an zif-connector you probably will need some type of of adapter. But generally speaking you can use the ipod harddrive in a regular laptop depending on you having the right adapter/connection in the laptop.(Example of an [adapter](http://www.addonics.com/products/aat18.php))

1.8" micro-sata connector:
[image: Micro-sata]

1.8" Zif connector:
[image: zif-connector found on ipod hard-drives]

Possible adapter:

[image: zif to 2.5" ide adapter]

Comment: The hard drive I'm looking at is on ebay - 1.8" TOSHIBA MK3008GAL

It needs to fit a Dell D420 mini-laptop. I don't even know what type of connector the laptop has, all I know is that it takes 1.8" HDDs.

Comment: It seems to be PATA

"You need a 1.8" PATA drive with a ZIF cable connector on it."

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/disk-drives/f/3534/p/19296994/19561781.aspx

Comment: I looked up the spec sheet of the dell D420 and it seems that the dell laptop actually uses a toshiba hard-drive with a ZIF-Connector so the  1.8" TOSHIBA MK3008GAL should just fit fine even without the need of an adapter. See: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/disk-drives/f/3534/p/18683462/18806448.aspx#18806448

Comment: @warsong here is the service manual on how to replace the hard-drive and it clearly shows that the d420 has a zif-connector. http://support.euro.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/latd420/en/sm_en/hddrive.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop takes 1.8" drives then yeah. I don't know where you would get one though. Smallest HDD I have seen in a laptop is 2.5"

You could buy some sort of adapter to get it to fit in a conventional laptop drive bay.